# Passing value to eventListener functions

Tags: javascript, dom

```
for ( var i=0; i<thumbs.length; i++) {
    var num = i;
    Core.addEventListener(thumbs[i], "click",  Slide.thumbClick);
}
```

In the above code, I want to pass the value of `var num` to the `thumbClick` eventlistener. but I am unable to. If I try to display that value, it gives an undefined value.
pls help

Comment: I don't understand... What is the code that isn't working? With the above code you're not passing `num` to anything.

Comment: the Slide.thumbClick cannot pass arguments. dont ask me why the Core library doesnt support such syntax. im a n00b here.

i somehow need to access this num value in other function. the num value is defined in this part but if i access it in any other funciton, it displays "undefined" value.

Comment: warning JS0040: variable num is assigned but never used on line 3 :)

Comment: What library are you using?  What are the 'Core' and 'Slide' objects/functions?

Comment: i am using the core library from sitepoint.com's ebook.
also the slide is the main object/function of the script.

Answer (score 1):

Don't remember for sure, but you should be able to do something like this:

```
Core.addEventListener(thumbs[i], "click", function() {
    //...do stuff here
});
```

var *num* should still be available to this anonymous function.

Comment: Very good hint.  When clicked, the 'this' becomes thumb[i].  Slide.thumbclick probably assumes another this.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to create a dynamic function.

Something like this. (I'm basing this on my experience with other ECMAScript-based languages, you might want to double-check to make sure this works.)

```
for ( var i=0; i<thumbs.length; i++)
{
        var num = i;
        Core.addEventListener(thumbs[i], "click",  new function(evt){
            Slide.thumbClick(num);
        });
}
```